# Blinking table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation

After adding a new set of data to a table view, i'd like to have the cell that displays the new  data blink green for 5 seconds. I used an extension to UIView. I call the extension within  "cellForRowAtIndexPath" but it turns the cell green permanently and it never turns back to default background color again. Heres the extension i am using:

```
extension UIView {
    func blink(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, alpha: CGFloat = 0.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            self.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        })
    
    }
}
```

self.blink() is called within "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

I have no idea why the animation isnt working, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: i thought the .autoreverse option would turn it back to original colour. of course then this would be only one blink but i was going to implement the repetition once i manage to have it blink once. could you tell me the right place to call this?

Comment: You need to wait until this cell is displayed. `cellForRowAt` is just an inquiry about what the cell should be. You cannot animate what isn't actually in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Ok matt, i think i found a way. Thanks for your time...

Comment: Yes, you're now waiting until `willDisplay`. That is definitely one way to do it. Be careful with your check for `shouldBlink` — keep in mind that cells are reused, so make sure your logic takes account of that. The blinking is not tied to the cell itself but to the position in the table view that it is assuming.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take care of that

Comment: Hey matt, I struggle to manage the reusing of cells. Table view cells added afterwards are blinking even though the logic doesnt apply to these. How can i make sure that only the cells that i want to blink, will blink?

Comment: I was afraid that might happen. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217327/discussion-between-nick-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

Heres a working answer i now managed to find for my problem.

First the blinking extension:

Using `.repeat .autoreverse` i wasnt able to stop the animation at the exact time that it turned back to default color which didnt look nice. So I decided to write the animation myself and let the cell blink 3 times this way:

```
extension UIView {
    func blink(duration: TimeInterval = 1.4, repetitions: Int = 3) {
        var remainingReps = repetitions
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.backgroundColor = Colors.primaryAlpha
        }) { (error) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                self.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
            }) { (error) in
                remainingReps -= 1
                if remainingReps > 0 {
                    self.blink(duration: duration, repetitions: remainingReps)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can choose yourself how many times you want the cell to blink by its "repetitions" parameter.
Now in your tableview add following code for `tableView willDisplay cell`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let dataSet = myData[indexPath.row]
        let myCell = cell as! YourCellType
            myCell.checkIfShouldBlink(data: dataSet)
        }

    }
```

Finally within your TableViewCell Class:

```
func checkIfShouldBlink(data: MyDataObject){
       //Here you can implement any kind of logic to have the cell blink depending
       //on your dataSet. In my case for exmaple, if the timestamp of the data is
       //less than 5 secs old (new Data) i have the cell blink.       
       
       if data.whatEverLogicYouWantToPutHere{
            self.blink()
       }
            

}
```